# Gnome 16.10 - Kernel Panic - not syncing VFS: Unable to mount root fs

Tags: kernel

after trying to open my computer, I realised that it showed me the grub menu instead of direct booting. After some tries, this error message is what comes up:

`Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`

How do we fix that?

Comment: I guess you recently ran a update ;)

Comment: @Arun I don't remember doing this at all!

Comment: i mean `sudo apt update`

Comment: I didn't at all..

Answer (score -1):

Start with a livecd, open a a terminal

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sdax /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
```

and now you can make update-initramfs and update-grub without errors.

```
update-initramfs -u -k 2.6.38-8-generic (or your version)
```

If you don't know your version. Use:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

And just update Grub.

```
update-grub2
```

Reboot your system.

Comment: Dude, I don't have a livecd.

Comment: Then from grub menu select `Advanced options for Ubuntu` and then select a older kernel